# XML stream writer library in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I have to generate single xml file by combining and processing multiple xmls of 100MB each approximately. I am not able to find any library of node.js which can stream write the xml.

I tried below libraries

1. xml-writer
2. xmlbuilder
3. genx

All these library store the xml in memory which leads to out of memory exception.

Do you have any suggestion for appropriate library which does not store complete object in memory.

Example code for one of the library(xml-writer)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var XMLWriter = require('xml-writer');

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("myfile",{
    encoding: 'utf-8'
 });

var xw = new XMLWriter(false);
xw.startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8').startElement(function() {
    return 'root';
});
for(var i = 0 ; i < 10000000; i++ ) {
    xw.startElement(function() {
        return 'root1';
    }).text(function() {
        return 'Some content1';
    });
    xw.endElement();
}
xw.endElement();
writeStream.write(xw.toString());
writeStream.end();
```

This is simple code for adding two elements in the file. But it is giving me out of memory exception. As it is creating one object and then storing complete object in the memory and writing it at once in the file.

I searched on google a lot but could not find any library which stream write the xml data to file.

Thanks,

Comment: You're using a non streamed xml generator. Try xml-stream and scramjet. The two together will output xml line by line.

Comment: @MichałCzapracki - But xml-stream is not a xml generator. I can use it to parse xml's but I need to do some transformation on them as well for which I was trying to use the above-mentioned libraries. If I use the combination you mentioned I would have to manually write xml tags.

Comment: I see, so you'd like something similar as those json to xml generator... I'm not sure if there's something like that now, but it could be easily written. I could try to look for something tomorrow, just let me know if I get this right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmlbuilder` [can do this](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki#begin-with-callback) using the 'callback' API.  You'd just have to write to your stream in the callback function.

For example:

```
const xmlbuilder = require('xmlbuilder');

const xml = xmlbuilder.begin(function(chunk) { process.stdout.write(chunk); });
xml
  .dec()
  .ele('root')
;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  xml.ele('example' + i).up();
}

xml
  .up()  // close <root/>
  .end()
;
```

Some parts of the API, such as the functions for moving around and altering nodes already generated - don't work in this callback mode because they aren't cached in memory.

Answer (score 3):

[xmbuilder2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder2) has a slightly different [callback API](https://oozcitak.github.io/xmlbuilder2/builder-functions-with-callbacks.html#createcb):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { createCB } = require('xmlbuilder2');

const ws = fs.createWriteStream('test.xml', {
  encoding: 'utf-8',
});

const xml = createCB({
  data: (text) => {
    ws.write(text);
  },
  prettyPrint: true,
});
xml.on('end', ws.close)

xml.dec().ele('root');

for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  xml.ele(`root${i}`).txt('Some content1').up();
}

xml
  .up()
  .end();
```

Comment: [xmlbuilder2 (repo)](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder2) is written in **TypeScript**, just in case you are using this language.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) to generate XML from an object stream, Karolis' answer above can be adapted like this, again using [xmlbuilder2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder2)'s [callback API](https://oozcitak.github.io/xmlbuilder2/builder-functions-with-callbacks.html#createcb):

```js
const {createCB} = require('xmlbuilder2');
const {Transform} = require('stream')

class xmlTransform extends Transform {

  constructor({
    root="root",
    row="row",
    prettyPrint=true,
    declaration=true,
  }={}){
    super({objectMode:true})  
    this.xml = createCB({
      data: text => this.push(text),
      prettyPrint,
    })
    this.row = row
    if(declaration) {this.xml.dec({"encoding":"UTF-8"})}
    this.xml.ele(root)
  }

  _transform (obj, encoding, done) {
    this.xml.ele(this.row).ele(obj).up()
    done()
  }

  _flush(done){
    this.xml.up().end()
    done()
  }
}
```

This can be tested something like this, here writing to a file:

```js
const {pipeline, Readable} = require('stream')
const fs = require('fs')

pipeline(
  Readable.from([
    {a:1,b:[2,3],c:{D:"four"}},
    {a:2,b:3},
  ]),
  new xmlTransform({
    root: "myroot",
    row: "row",
    prettyPrint: true,
    declaration: true
  }),
  fs.createWriteStream("test.xml"), // or process.stdout,
  (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    console.log("done")
  }
)
```

...and gives output like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myroot>
  <row>
    <a>
      1
    </a>
    <b>
      2
    </b>
    <b>
      3
    </b>
    <c>
      <D>
        four
      </D>
    </c>
  </row>
  <row>
    <a>
      2
    </a>
    <b>
      3
    </b>
  </row>
</myroot>
```

You could replace the `Readable.from` in the test with an object stream based on your source XML files, perhaps using [`xml-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-stream) or otherwise.

Using a transform stream like this to separate out producing XML from writing the file can give a little more flexiblity, and using [`pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback) saves mucking around with stream events.